# Why is PostgreSQL not using my indexes on a small table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have the following table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE index_test
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    text varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
    last_modified timestamp NOT NULL,
    value int,
    item_type varchar(2046)
);
CREATE INDEX idx_index_type ON index_test ( item_type );
CREATE INDEX idx_index_value ON index_test ( value )
```

I make the following selects:

```
explain select * from index_test r where r.item_type='B';
explain select r.value from index_test r where r.value=56;
```

The explanation of execution plan looks like this:

```
Seq Scan on index_test r  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=1 width=1576)
    Filter: ((item_type)::text = 'B'::text)'
```

As far as I understand, this is a full table scan. The question is: why my indexes are not used?

May be, the reason is that I have too few rows in my table? I have only 20 of them. Could you please provide me with a SQL statement to easily populate my table with random data to check the indexes issue?

I have found this article: http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/db2luw/how-to-easily-populate-a-table-with-random-data-7888, but it doesn't work for me. The efficiency of the statement does not matter, only the simplicity.

Comment: If efficiency doesn't matter, only simplicity, why do you care whether it's using an index or not? Indexes are performance optimisations that don't affect semantics - well, with the exception of implementation details like Pg's UNIQUE indexes as implementation for UNIQUE constraints.

Comment: Craig, "efficiency doesn't matter" relates only to the way of inserting the dummy rows, sorry for misleading phrase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Maybe, the reason is that I have too few rows in my table?*

Yes. For a total of 20 rows in a table a seq scan is always going to be faster than an index scan. Chances are that those rows are located in a single database block anyway, so the seq scan would only need a single I/O operation.

If you use

```
explain (analyze true, verbose true, buffers true) select ....
```

you can see a bit more details about what is really going on.

Btw: you shouldn't use `text` as a column name, as that is also a datatype in Postgres (and thus a reserved word).

Comment: @KutaBeach Note that you can force index scans for the purpose of testing whether it's *possible* to use an index for a particular query by using the `enable_` parameters as documented in the manual. These parameters are for testing purposes only and should not generally be used in production.

Answer (score 2):

The example you have found is for DB2, in pg you can use `generate_series` to do it.
For example like this:

```
INSERT INTO index_test(data,last_modified,value,item_type) 
SELECT
    md5(random()::text),now(),floor(random()*100),md5(random()::text) 
    FROM generate_series(1,1000);
SELECT max(value) from index_test;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/52641/3

The second query in above fiddle should use index only scan.